# Data structure for grouping items and mapping individual items to other group members

Tags: c++, sql, data-structures, mapping, grouping

I'm in a situation where I need to create groups of entities (specifically, file names).  Then, when given a particular file name, I need to obtain its other group members. My current solution involves placing file names in a SQLite table with two columns: file name and an integer group id.  When given a file name, I run a query like this:

```
SELECT file_name FROM files WHERE group_id =
(SELECT group_id FROM files WHERE file_name = "sampleFileName.docx")
```

I'm wondering if there's any more suitable or performant solution to this problem. For example, is there another data structure to consider?  Perhaps one that could be serialized, or constructed from the database table?  Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine, as long as a `file_name` is a unique key (else, the subquery might return multiple records, which would generate a runtime error).

This can also be expressed with a self-join:

```
select f.file_name 
from files f
inner join files g on g.group_id = f.group_id
where g.file_name = 'sampleFileName.docx'
```

Comment: Do you know if the join is faster than the nested select?

Answer (score 0):

Your query would return no data if sub-query return `null`, so you can use  `exists` instead :

```
select f.*
from files f
where exists (select 1 
              from files ff 
              where ff.group_id = f.group_id and 
                    ff.file_name = 'sampleFileName.docx'
             );
```

Perfomance would be better if you have index `files (group_id,file_name)`.